# Get the current position of moving element - on mouse click

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML element that is moving from point A to point B.

I want to get the specific position of this element when I click the mouse while the element is moving to point B.

How can I do this?

**HTML**

```
<div id="contentContainer">
  <div id="thing"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#thing {
border-radius: 50%;
position: absolute;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
background-color: red;
transition: 1s cubic-bezier(.5, .51, .7, .68),
            1s cubic-bezier(.5, .51, .7, .68);
```

}

**js**

```
var theThing= document.querySelector("#thing");
var container = document.querySelector("#contentContainer");

//create random position to move the #thing to it 
var xPosition =  Math.random()*(container.clientWidth-40);
var yPosition = Math.random()*(container.clientHeight-40);

// add the new position  
theThing.style.left = xPosition + "px";
theThing.style.top = yPosition + "px";

container.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
//here i want to click to get current specific position of #thing
}
```

Comment: You can console log the xPosition & yPosition?

Comment: position  x and y is the finished position of the element (point B position)

Comment: I'm sorry for not understanding. Would you like to track the position of thing as it moves?

Comment: am sorry for my poor discribe. yes i want to track the position

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
// Code goes here
window.onload = function() {
  var theThing = document.querySelector("#thing");
  var container = document.querySelector("#contentContainer");

  //create random position to move the #thing to it 
  var xPosition = Math.random() * (container.clientWidth - 40);
  var yPosition = Math.random() * (container.clientHeight - 40);

  // add the new position  
  theThing.style.left = xPosition + "px";
  theThing.style.top = yPosition + "px";
  document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var pos = getPosition(theThing);
    alert(pos.top + "," + pos.left);
  });
}

function getPosition(element) {
  var x = window.scrollX + element.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  var y = window.scrollY + element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  return {
    top: x,
    left: y
  };
}
```